# How can I fix apple mach-o linker error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, ld

When I run the program I get the below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "QCARUnityPlayer::getInstance()", referenced from:
      -[DisplayConnection recreateSurface:] in DisplayManager.o
      -[UnityView layoutSubviews] in UnityView.o
      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o
      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o
      -[UnityAppController applicationWillTerminate:] in UnityAppController.o
    "QCARUnityPlayer::QCARNotifyCreated(int, int)", referenced from:
          -[DisplayConnection recreateSurface:] in DisplayManager.o
     "QCARUnityPlayer::QCARSetOrientation(int)", referenced from:
          -[UnityView layoutSubviews] in UnityView.o
          -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o
      "QCARUnityPlayer::destroy()", referenced from:
          -[UnityAppController applicationWillTerminate:] in UnityAppController.o
  "QCARUnityPlayer::QCARInit(char const*)", referenced from:
      -[UnityAppController applicationDidBecomeActive:] in UnityAppController.o
  "QCARUnityPlayer::QCARPause(bool)", referenced from:
      -[UnityAppController applicationWillResignActive:] in UnityAppController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have to be sure that you have i386 versions of all your 3. party frameworks you are using.

Comment: How can I do this, can you help me ?

Answer (score -1):

This error is usually caused because some file is not being able to read.